# As a plugin developer, how do I remove a plugin from the global plugin directory?

Tags: plugin-development

I currently have a plugin in the global WordPress plugin directory that I'd like to remove. It is currently broken, outdated, and I do not intend to provide continuing support for it. To spare people the heartbreak of installing it, I'd like to remove it.

Unfortunately Google is flooded with how to remove plugins installed on WordPress sites, so that makes it hard to find a clear answer for this.

Comment: Just send an email to plugins AT wordpress.org and they will take care for you

Comment: @Mike as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the content of your plugin directory using subversion in the SVN repository.

```
svn co http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your-plugin your-plugin
```

In other words, these instructions may help you update the plugin files.

```
svn status
svn update
svn commit -m "Emptied my plugins..."
```

If you need to delete files use this

```
svn st | grep '^!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn delete --force
```

**Ref.** [1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/) and [2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/faq/)

---

I think you will also need to send an email to plugins at wordpress.org, but they occasionally remove empty directories.

When I first wrote to this email address the great Otto replied. Enjoy.

Comment: Since April 2020 you can do it yourself from wordpress.org "Go to the ADVANCED VIEW link on sidebar of your plugin page and scroll down to the CLOSE THIS PLUGIN section."
Also, you don't have to delete from SVN